# Tomee - Hibernate Invalid and non-convertable constructor parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, openejb

im trying to deploy my application in TOMEE with Hibernate 4, I already copz all the hibernate libraries in /lib but im getting the next error.
Is there any special configuration to make hibernate work with TomEEE?,

Thanks in advance

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.openejb.hibernate.OpenEJBJtaPlatform cannot be cast to org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform